# Removing members from request from controller before doing a REST call

Tags: java, angularjs, rest

I am new in angularjs so if my question seems trivial kindly pardon.

I have a class which i am getting from a fetch API lets say

```
Class RequestObject {

     private String member1;
     private String member2;
     private String member3;
     private String member4;

    //getter setters

}
```

I am getting an Object of this class through a fetch API and want to use this object to call another API but the request object for the 2nd API consumes only lets say member1 and member2.

To call the second API i am manually deleting member3 and member4.

Is there another way around.
Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If using Jackson API we can use @JsonIgnore to remove unwanted members from the request object.